# What has happned to the Deco Grid System

Tags: grid, plone

Does anyone know if the Deco Grid System is being abandoned?

The original page at:

http://deco.gs/

...no longer seems to be available.

Would really like to know if this is toast before using it in a project.

Answer (score 4):

I'm having some issues with the .gs registrar, currently in the process of getting the site back online. Sorry about the temporary disruption.

The new site is here: http://limi.net/deco.gs

Answer (score 3):

It is not being abandoned, to my knowledge. I think there has been some trouble with the .gs registrar.  The code is still available at http://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/sandbox/deco-grids/